# Access content outside CakePhp folder

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.0

I have a CakePHP project uploaded to the server:

> - httpdocs/cakephp/app/...

My domain name, for example www.mydomain.com is directed to httpdocs/cakephp
Now.. I need to access an image folder that it's otside the webroot of CakePhp:

> - httpdocs/resources/images/...

The problem is that I can't see files outside the cakephp folder when I go to www.mydomain.com, If I try with ../../resources/images.... I just get www.mydomain.com/resoures/images with an error.

How can I solve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) the resouces folder in your webroot folder.

Alternatively you can send the files through php. The CakePHP book describes this [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html) for >2.3 and [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file).

Also it is not a good idea to put the whole cake folder in the root of your domain, you should set your app/webroot has the root of your host.

Comment: Great! Symlink worked like a charm. Thank you burzum!